# Need help implementing aspects for toggle bar

Tags: html, css

Basically, I am trying to create a toggle bar with a day and night system. Once you toggle the bar, it either leads to day or night. I have the toggle bar, but I am having trouble implementing the day and night system. Once the user toggles to day or night, I want the background to be light blue for day and black for dark blue for night. I want the colors to switch depending if the user is on day or night. How can I do this? The toggle code is down below. Here is the link for the code I am using if it's easier to read in this format: https://codepen.io/bnthor/pen/WQBNxO

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="toggleWrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="dn" id="dn"/>
  <label for="dn" class="toggle">
    <span class="toggle__handler">
      <span class="crater crater--1"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--2"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--3"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star star--1"></span>
    <span class="star star--2"></span>
    <span class="star star--3"></span>
    <span class="star star--4"></span>
    <span class="star star--5"></span>
    <span class="star star--6"></span>
  </label>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
     background-color: #1e314f;
     font-family: 'Helvetica Rounded', 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     color: #fff;
}
 .toggleWrapper {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 0 200px;
     transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
 .toggleWrapper input {
     position: absolute;
     left: -99em;
}
 .toggle {
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     width: 90px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: #83d8ff;
     border-radius: 84px;
     transition: background-color 200ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
 .toggle:before {
     content: 'AM';
     position: absolute;
     left: -50px;
     top: 15px;
     font-size: 18px;
}
 .toggle:after {
     content: 'PM';
     position: absolute;
     right: -48px;
     top: 15px;
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #749ed7;
}
 .toggle__handler {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 3px;
     left: 3px;
     width: 44px;
     height: 44px;
     background-color: #ffcf96;
     border-radius: 50px;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
     transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
 .toggle__handler .crater {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #e8cda5;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
     border-radius: 100%;
}
 .toggle__handler .crater--1 {
     top: 18px;
     left: 10px;
     width: 4px;
     height: 4px;
}
 .toggle__handler .crater--2 {
     top: 28px;
     left: 22px;
     width: 6px;
     height: 6px;
}
 .toggle__handler .crater--3 {
     top: 10px;
     left: 25px;
     width: 8px;
     height: 8px;
}
 .star {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #fff;
     transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
     border-radius: 50%;
}
 .star--1 {
     top: 10px;
     left: 35px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 30px;
     height: 3px;
}
 .star--2 {
     top: 18px;
     left: 28px;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 30px;
     height: 3px;
}
 .star--3 {
     top: 27px;
     left: 40px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 30px;
     height: 3px;
}
 .star--4, .star--5, .star--6 {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: all 300ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
 .star--4 {
     top: 16px;
     left: 11px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
     transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}
 .star--5 {
     top: 32px;
     left: 17px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 3px;
     height: 3px;
     transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}
 .star--6 {
     top: 36px;
     left: 28px;
     z-index: 0;
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
     transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle {
     background-color: #749dd6;
}
 input:checked + .toggle:before {
     color: #749ed7;
}
 input:checked + .toggle:after {
     color: #fff;
}
 input:checked + .toggle .toggle__handler {
     background-color: #ffe5b5;
     transform: translate3d(40px, 0, 0) rotate(0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .toggle__handler .crater {
     opacity: 1;
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--1 {
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--2 {
     width: 4px;
     height: 4px;
     transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--3 {
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
     transform: translate3d(-7px, 0, 0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--4, input:checked + .toggle .star--5, input:checked + .toggle .star--6 {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--4 {
     transition: all 300ms 200ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--5 {
     transition: all 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
 input:checked + .toggle .star--6 {
     transition: all 300ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for pure CSS answer, or will the JS be good enough?

Comment: If you can provide it with just CSS. If not, JS is fine also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just edit body element like:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="body">
<div class="toggleWrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="dn" id="dn" onclick="changeBack()"/>
    <label for="dn" class="toggle">
    <span class="toggle__handler">
      <span class="crater crater--1"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--2"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--3"></span>
    </span>
        <span class="star star--1"></span>
        <span class="star star--2"></span>
        <span class="star star--3"></span>
        <span class="star star--4"></span>
        <span class="star star--5"></span>
        <span class="star star--6"></span>
    </label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And you can use javascript to change background:

```
 <script>
    function changeBack() {
        var checkBox = document.getElementById("dn");
        if (checkBox.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
    }

</script>
```

**EDITED**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="dn" id="dn" onclick="changeBack()"/>
```

and all JS

Comment: Would I need to edit anything in the JS code such as true?

Comment: I dont understand your question. It saying if checbox is checked so its change body background color to lightblue and if not change it to black. You can change colors to any.

Comment: I am trying to implement the code you provided but for some reason, it doesn't work. Could this be because of the JS? Sorry if my previous question was confusing.

Comment: In the CSS put the id (#) before body?

Comment: No I mean if you edited body tag in HTML like `<body id="body">`

Comment: So if you check checkbox it have to work i already tryed that two times :)

Comment: I put the code in the link I provided (Codepen) and it works. But for some reason, the software I am using which is repl.it doesn't work

Comment: The only JS code I have is the one you provided. Other than that, other JS codes do work.

Comment: If you want I can change it to JQUERY if it works there

Comment: I don't think it does. The only languages it provides is HTML, CSS, and JS.

Comment: I think it will be problem at you software I will try to find other solution

Comment: I found new solution... I edited my post... I tryed that in repl.it and it works for me..

Comment: @Manan You are welcome! Please submit this answer thanks!